# Changing colours in GeoPandas?

Tags: python, shapefile, symbology, geopandas

I have a very simple map (http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/download/bytes/nybb_15b.zip) and I have never before worked with shapefiles in any way. Can someone tell me what I need to do in order to change each borough's colour and to remove the outline? (Usually I use Python.)

The map below was made with (Geo-)Pandas. But after a few hours of research, I don't even know whether the colours could be changed with something that comes with the Anaconda package.

```
boros = GeoDataFrame.from_file('nybb/nybb.shp')
boros.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: It is something you have to change in the rendering software (geo-pandas), since SHP files do not contain colour information.

Comment: Oh, that is a quite a surprise to me right now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Geopandas [plot takes a colormap parameter](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot)

The parameter is called `cmap`. There's an alias for it called `colormap` but it should not be used anymore.

```
GeoDataFrame.plot(column=None, cmap=None, alpha=0.5, categorical=False, legend=False, axes=None)
```

The [pandas documentation mentions colormaps](http://geopandas.org/mapping.html#choosing-colors) such as

```
cmap='cubehelix'
cmap='Greens'
cmap='winter'
```

Comment: Thanks underdark. Your links are dead. I guess these are current addresses for [1st](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot) and [2nd](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html#choosing-colors). BTW colour maps are ready-made choices, which I might not like for my map. Worth to see [this way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336437/colorizing-polygons-based-on-color-values-in-dataframe-column/336455#336455) of assigning your own colour-choices to each feature row? (based on a given column value)