# Change Color in GeoPandas Plot

Tags: python, color, geopandas, plot

My question has overlap with [Changing colours in GeoPandas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152920/changing-colours-in-geopandas), but unfortunately still unanswered: I want to plot a multiline shapefile in 1 color.

```
import geopandas as gpd
multiline_example = gpd.read_file('multiline_example_filepath.shp')
multiline_example.plot()
```

This works fine so far, except that the lines have multiple random colors:

[image: Plot with random colors]

Now I simply want to assign 1 color for all lines. Is this possible, and if so, how?

**What I found so far:**

On the GeoPandas site, some plotting-examples are given (http://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mapping.html). Here, they simply use

```
multiline_example.plot(color='green')
```

However, if I try this, I get the following error:

TypeError: plot_dataframe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'

Why doesn't this work?

I have been able to choose a column (where the color is dependent on the column values), as well as a colormap, but the results are still different colors for different lines.

```
multiline_example.plot(colormap = 'Greens')
multiline_example.plot(column = 'a_column_name')
```

---

Simply by updating from GeoPandas 0.1.1 to 0.3.0.

```
multiline_example.plot(color='green')
```

works fine now.

Comment: what is your geopandas version ?

Comment: That's a good question, I get where things went wrong now.. For some reason I had installed geopandas version 0.1.1. After updating to 0.3.0, everything worked fine. Sorry for bad research from my side, thanks for the clarifying question.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your own color map with matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap = ListedColormap(['red'], name='allred')
GeoSeries(bldgs).plot(cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

BTW I think I'm using a different version to you as colormap changed to cmap for me (0.3.0).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer with example. Found out now that I was using an old version, 0.1.1. After updating everything works as should, a simple plot() already shows 1 color.

Comment: No worries. I was having the opposite problem, after upgrading I no longer had colour differentiation so had to add in cmap, edgecolour and alpha to get it working like before.